# ACF Repeater Field - display first 3 fields and the rest in toggle

Tags: javascript, wordpress, toggle, repeater, advanced-custom-fields

I am helping a friend coding a movie website with wordpress. He wants to show the filmcast (using Advanced Custom Fields, Repeater Field) on each movie page as follows:

The first three actors (with name as permalink, role and pic) should be displayed openly in a row of three and the rest of them inside a toggle, which can be opend with a “see more” link and closed with a “see less” link.

This is the example, he showed me to understand what he whishes it should look like: https://www.moviepilot.de/movies/the-justice-league

I am working on it since days and have the code ALMOST working. But coding, especially Java Script and ACF are pretty new to me, so I can’t find a solution for two problems:

- I have ALL actors inside the toggle now (how to get the first three actors outside the toggle?)
- I have only a static button which opens and closes the toggle, but not a “see more” link to open the toggle and a “see less” to close it (as on the example movie page).

I tried every code snippet I found with google, here and on the ACF website. But it seems I am totaly lost.  Every help will be very much appreciated!!!
Here is the code I have so far:

```
<style>
#filmcast-toggle {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 80px 0;
    display: none;
}
</style>



<button onClick="myFunction()">Show/Hide Cast</button>

<div id="filmcast-toggle">

<div class="filmcast-element"> 

//Page-Element ACF Filmcast    
<?php $i = 0; ?>

<?php 
    // check if the repeater field has rows of data
   if( have_rows('filmcast') ):

    // loop through the rows of data
   while ( have_rows('filmcast') ) : the_row(); ?> 

<?php if($i == 0) { echo '<div class="filmcast-row">'; } ?>

<div class="filmcast-half">
    <div class="filmcast-person">                           

    <?php $posts = get_sub_field('filmcast-person');

        if( $posts ): ?>

        <?php foreach( $posts as $post): setup_postdata($post); ?>

            <div class="filmcast-image">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail ( array (120, 140));  ?>
            </div>

            <div class="filmcast-name"> 
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>">
            <?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?></a>
            </div>

            <div class="filmcast-rolle">
            <?php the_sub_field('filmcast-rolle'); ?>
            </div>

        <?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata (); ?>

<?php endif;?>

 </div> 
    </div>

<?php $i++; if($i == 3) {   $i = 0;     echo '</div>'; } ?>     

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php if($i > 0) {  echo '</div>'; } ?>

         <?php else :
            // no rows found

          endif; ?> </div>
</div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('filmcast-toggle');
    if (x.style.display === 'none'|| x.style.display == '') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you could insert a counter, add to the counter everytime that an actor is outputtet, if counter == 2 then insert a start div, and remember the closing div when the loop ends - toggleSlide that div with jquery - and change the text when you toggle - hope it helps

Comment: Thanks alot, Stender, that sounds pretty good. I tried this, but unfortunately I failed miserably to convert your words into code. Where and how would I have to add this to my code?